# Remove attribute from mongoid database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, mongoid

I have a model User in mongoid with attribute :country. I want to remove this field from the model and from any existing user documents. How can I achieve this?

```
# user.rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name,     type: String
  #field :country,  type: String    --> field removed from model

end
```

Answer (score 3):

For all users in the database:

```
User.all.each { |user| user.unset(:country) }
```

or for a single user:

```
User.unset(:country)
```

Comment: You could also use the `$unset` operator and the low level Moped interface.

Comment: unset is only for unset the value of attribute, not for remove the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoid 3+ `User.all.unset(:country)` will unset the field for all `User` documents atomically:

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Atomic#unset-instance_method